# If $g = (~g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_n(x)~)$ is a vector valued function, $f$ is a scalar field, $h=f[g(x)] $ , then what is the value of $\nabla h(x)?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $g = (~g_1(x),g_2(x),...,g_n(x)~)$ is a vector valued function, $f$ is a scalar field, $h=f[g(x)] $ , then what is the value of $\nabla h(x)?$

**Attempt:**

$h(x) = f[g(x)] \implies h(x) = (~ f[g_1(x)]~~f(g_2(x)]\cdots f(g_n(x)~)$

$\implies \partial h/\partial x_1 = f_{x_1}[g(x)] \cdot (~\partial g_1 /\partial x_1 ~~ \cdots~~~ \partial g_n/ \partial x_1~)$

$ 
   \nabla h(x)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   ~ f_{x_1}[g_1(x)].\partial g_1 /\partial x_1& ~~ \cdots~~ f_{x_1}[g_1(x)].\partial g_n/ \partial x_1~  \\
   ~f_{x_2}[g_2(x)].\partial g_1 /\partial x_2& ~~ \cdots~~ f_{x_2}[g_2(x)].\partial g_n/ \partial x_2~  \\
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\cdots~ \\
  \end{array} } \right]
 $

Could anyone please confirm if this is correct?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's incorrect. Since $g = (g_1,\ldots, g_n)$, $h(x)$ is equal to $f(g_1(x),\ldots, g_n(x))$, not $(f(g_1(x)),\ldots, f(g_n(x)))$. Let $u_1 = g_1(x), u_2 = g_2(x),\ldots, u_n = g_n(x)$. Then $h(x) = f(u_1,\ldots, u_n)$, and by the chain rule, $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_j} \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_j} \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i} = \nabla f \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}.$$

Therefore $$\nabla h(x) = \left(\nabla f(g(x)) \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x),\ldots, \nabla f(g(x))\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}(x)\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I have one more question please. Is the above $= \nabla h(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n D_k f(b)~ \nabla g_k(a)$? Thanks

Comment: If $b = g(a)$, yes that looks right.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a suitable form of the chain rule.  Given a vector $a$,

$$a \cdot \nabla (f \circ g)|_x = [(a \cdot \nabla) g |_x] \cdot \nabla f |_{g(x)}$$

The term in square brackets is the Jacobian $\underline g$ acting on the vector $a$, so this can be written

$$a \cdot \nabla (f \circ g)|_x = \underline g(a)|_x \cdot \nabla f|_{g(x)}$$

Just switch $a$ and $\nabla f$ at the cost of a transpose:

$$a \cdot \nabla (f \circ g)|_x  = \underline g^T(\nabla f|_{g(x)})|_x \cdot a$$

$a$ is arbitrary, so you can eliminate it from both sides to get the result:

$$\nabla (f \circ g)|_x = \underline g^T(\nabla f|_{g(x)})|_x$$